# Why is my app using so many instances when I have so few requests?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine

My webapp gets about 0.4 requests per second. Does it really need 2-3 instances running all day long? Why is the "active" line in the graph so much lower than the "billed"? Note: I'm using F4 frontend instances... Not sure how that factors into this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your "idle instances" setting?

Comment: Might be something in your code, are you using Python?

Comment: @knego It's a Java app, and idle instances is 1-1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using F4 instances, you are being billed 4x.

Comment: But why does it vary between 2 and 3?

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. If your app can run within the limits of F1 instances, I suggest you just try to "downgrade" and see what happens... It will be enlightening for a lot of us.